# Excel number format for abbreviation

Tags: excel, number-formatting, conditional-formatting

Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
Value           Display
1               1
11              11
111             111
1111            1.11k
11111           11.11k
111111          111.11k
1111111         1.11M
11111111        11.11M
111111111       111.11M
1111111111      1.11B
11111111111     11.11B
111111111111    111.11B
```

This is the format that a Bloomberg terminal uses to display currency figures. Numbers don't go past `B`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
[>999999999.999]#,,,"B";[>999999.999]#,,"M";#,##0_M
```

I stole it from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2228-excel-abbreviate-numbers.html) and I cannot find documentation that shows how to improve it.

Comment: You can only have two conditions and one default in a custom number format. See [Formula for smart, scale-aware number-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77974/formula-for-smart-scale-aware-number-formatting-in-google-sheets-e-g-1-024-%E2%86%92/78069#78069). To add others, use a CFR based on the numerical value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using conditions in a custom number format, you can have a maximum of two conditions with one default number format and one default text format.

```
[>=1000000000]#0.0#,,, \B;[>=1000000]#0.0#,, \M;#0.0#, K
```

[image]

To attain your fourth criteria, you need something that will override the custom number format. A Conditional Formatting Rule seems appropriate here. Create one based on the following formula,

```
=$b2<10^3
```

Click Format then the Number tab and set the custom number format for `0_)`.

[image]

Of course, that CFR number format potentially could be two more conditions and a default but you only require a single additional number format.